# TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've written a simple Firestore function that fetches the data and is supposed to make a few comparisons with the written value. But weirdly, it's saying that 'snapshot.val' is not a function. What's wrong with my code?

```
exports.checkIfScannerExists = functions.firestore.document('Checking_Scanner/{push_id}').onCreate((change, context) => {
if(!change.before.data())
{
    const push_id = context.params.push_id;
    const phone_number = change.after.data().Phone;

    console.log("Phone is:", phone_number)
    
    admin.firestore().collection('Store_Logins').where('Phone', '==', phone_number).get()
    .then(snapshot => {

        console.log(snapshot.val())

        if(snapshot.empty)
        {
            admin.firestore().collection('Checking_Scanner').doc(push_id).set({
                "Response": "No"
            }, {merge: true})
            
            return "nope."
        }
        else
        {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
              });

           admin.firestore().collection('Checking_Scanner').doc(push_id).set({
                "Response": "Yes",
            }, {merge: true})

            return "yes"
        }

    })

}

else
{
    return null;
}

return null;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
console.log(snapshot.val());
```

into this:

```
console.log(snapshot.data());
```

`val()` is used with realtime database while `data()` is used with firestore.

Comment: This answer is misleading. snapshot.data() will also give us the same error (snapshot.data is not a function)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379124/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-snapshot-data-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to

Comment: snapshot.val() only works when targeting a specific doc and not running a query. 

For example:

admin.firestore.collection('Store_Logins').doc("docKey").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let personalItem = snapshot.data();
})